# how to fix undefined index on $_GET?

Tags: php, get, http-headers, isset

I am unable to understand how to fix this notice. It gives a undefined index on a `$_GET[' ']` and I cannot set a `isset()` as it'll brake the query and code.

`class.php`

```
private $perPage = 8;
private $startPage = 0; 

public function latestArticles()
{
    if($_GET['page'] <= 1) NOTICE ERROR <-- is here on the $_GET['page'];
        $this->startPage = 0;
    else
        $this->startPage = $_GET['page'] * $this->perPage - $this->perPage;

    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    $sth->execute(array($this->startPage, $this->perPage));

    $data = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $data;
}
```

And this code which sets the header if the button is clicked(next or previous button). If you first load the page, there is no header it loads like ex: www.site.com/ so it gives the error as there are no `$_GET['page']` being set, but I cannot get around this issue.. this here is how I am printing the data being retrieved by the function.

`index.php`

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
        $page = 1;
    else 
        $page = $_GET['page'];

    foreach($latestArticles as $article)
    {
        $title = $article['title'];

        echo ''.$title.'';
    }

    $prev = $page-1;
    $next = $page+1;

    echo "
    <a class='nxt_prevButton' href='?page=$prev'>previous page</a>
    <a class='nxt_prevButton' href='?page=$next'>next page</a>
    ";
?>
```

### failed attempts

I have set the `isset()` and `empty()` but it doesn't allow the code to work which is a next and previous button for more results, 8 results per page. (notice goes away but code (query) stops working).

What is a way to get around this, by fixing the code? WITHOUT using **error_reporting(0);** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to use `isset`, it's just a matter of working out the logic.

I think, if I understand this right, that you could do this:

```
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] <= 1)
    $this->startPage = 0;
else
    $this->startPage = $_GET['page'] * $this->perPage - $this->perPage;
```

So if `$_GET['page']` isn't set, `startPage` will be 0.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thank you. Should you ALWAYS use isset or are there specifications to when?

Comment: @iBrazilian2 If you want to avoid the "undefined index" notice that you are getting, you have to check for an array index before trying to access it, yes.